# Why the css not applied when orientation change?

Tags: css, media-queries

I am using media query. I have device having width 360, height:640. Actually I add border to check the css applied or not when orientation change.

But it only show border red when I change the orientation. It is not showing other border why?

```
@media screen and (max-width: 360px), screen and (max-height: 640px)and (orientation: portrait) {
    .subcontent_h {
        height: 200px;
        overflow: auto;
        margin-top: 10px;
        border: 1px solid deeppink !important;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 640px) , screen and (max-height: 360px)and (orientation: landscape) {
    .subcontent_h {
        height: 200px;
        overflow: auto;
        margin-top: 10px;
        border: 1px solid red !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked your device understands the colour deeppink? Try replacing it with green or something similar.

Comment: ok I will check using black

Comment: BTW why is this question tagged with javascript and jquery, where it does not have to do anything with that.

Comment: @scragar i used black but it not working

Answer (score 1):

> Order of Specification: As a last resort, when all other conflict
>   resolution specifications cannot determine which style should take
>   precedence, the last style specified will be the style used.

```
.subcontent_h{
    height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
    margin-top: 10px; 
}

@media screen and (max-width: 640px) , screen and (max-height: 360px)and (orientation: landscape) {
    .subcontent_h {
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 360px), screen and (max-height: 640px)and (orientation: portrait) {
    .subcontent_h {       
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LqR4A/1/)

Comment: you can just swap the 2 @media rules instead of using `!important` flag here.

Answer (score 0):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 360px), (min-device-width: 360px) and (max-device-width: 640px) and (orientation : portrait) {
/* CSS */ 
}


@media screen and (min-width: 360px) and (max-width:640px), (min-device-width: 360px) and
(max-device-width: 640px) and (orientation : landscape) {
/* CSS */ 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First Use Modernizer to check weather your device support media queries

Make sure you have added below meta tag in head section

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
```

Try Below way

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 360px) and (max-height: 640px)
    {
      .subcontent_h {
         height: 200px;
         overflow: auto;
         margin-top: 10px;
         border: 1px solid deeppink !important;
      }
    }

  @media screen and (max-width: 640px) and (max-height: 320px)
   {
    .subcontent_h {
       height: 200px;
       overflow: auto;
       margin-top: 10px;
       border: 1px solid red!important;
   }
}
```